# bind user control to contentcontrol validation rules not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, user-controls, validationrules

I have many user controls and i have main window which contains a content control and list box  when user select from list box i bound the selected user control to the content control the problem is when the user control bound for the first time the validation rules is appears but when user control bound for the second time the validation rules disappear what is the problem ?
here is the main window :

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="FormsListBox" Margin="0,5,0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Width="180" ItemsSource="{Binding Formlist}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFormInfo}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Resources/Capture.PNG" ></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormName}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MainStackPanel" >
        <ContentControl  Content="{Binding Path=SelectedFormInfo.MainForm}">

        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

here is the sample of validation role in user control:

```
<StackPanel Width="315" Margin="20,0,10,0">
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtWeaponNumber" Width="315">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="SelectedWeapon.weaponNumber" Mode="TwoWay"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True"
                ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:RequiredRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**Note:** MainForm in SelectedFormInfo contains thee selected user control

Answer (score 0):

i set my user control in AdornerDecorator and the Validation did not disappear